# Passing parameter received from shell script to a db2 query inside same shell script

Tags: bash, shell, db2, db2-luw

I am writing a shell script which takes 1 parameter table name. Inside the same shell script I have a db2 query - "Select * from table_name". I want to provide a table name for db2 query which I received from shell script parameter. How do I achieve this.

My Script so far -

```
    echo "Content Display"
        while [ -n "$1" ]; do
          case "$1" in
          -f) echo "File mode has selected" ;;
          --)
          shift
          break
          ;;
    esac
    shift
    done
    param = "$1"
    db2 "select * from 'param'"
```

Comment: Could you post your script so far to give people a starting point and see exactly what you're trying to do? without that the most useful thing people can do is probably just link you to documentation.

Comment: Sorry my bad, updated the post

Comment: Is your question "how do I use a variable in a string in bash?"

Comment: I am storing value received from parameter into a variable called param. I want to use the variable in db2 query. So basically user will provide a table name and I want to return contents of the table by running a db2 select query on it.

Comment: I think you mean `db2 "select * from ${param}"` instead of `db2 "select * from 'param'"`?

Answer (score 1):

To expand a variable in a double quoted string, just put a `$` in front of the variable name:

```
param="world"
echo "Hello $param"
```

In your case:

```
param="$1"
db2 "select * from $param"
```

If you ever need to disambiguate, you can use `${}`:

```
param="29"
echo "It is $paramC outside"  # Wrong, accesses $paramC
echo "It is ${param}C outside # Right, accesses $param and appends the letter C
```

Answer (score 1):

Here would be a sample shell script based on your requirement.  It is verifed on AIX and Linux.

1. Save below as prep.sh, run "chmod 777 prep.sh" and execute it.

```
#!/bin/sh

# prepare objects for test
db2 -v "drop db db1"
db2 -v "create db db1"
db2 -v "connect to db1"
db2 -v "create table hotel (c1 char(20))"
db2 -v "insert into hotel values ('Nice hotel')"
db2 -v "insert into hotel values ('Good hotel')"
db2 -v "insert into hotel values ('Fancy hotel')"
db2 -v "terminate"
```

2. Save below as get.sh and run "chmod 777 get.sh".

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
  echo "no table name"
  exit
else
  tabname=$1
fi

db2 -v "connect to db1"
db2 -v "select * from $tabname"
db2 -v "terminate"
```

3. Execute get.sh as below:

./get.sh hotel

**Note:**
It connects database **db1**, select **hotel** table and then returns **three rows** as below:

```
C1
--------------------
Nice hotel
Good hotel
Fancy hotel

  3 record(s) selected.
```

Hope this helps.